# Как просмотреть выполняемый запрос, сгенерированный peewee?

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee, sql-injection

Попробовал провести sql-инъекцию, но результата не было. Но если вывести запрос, то он рабочий.

#### Подготовил код для тестирования:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

db.connect()
db.create_tables([Person])

for i in range(5):
    Person(name=f'name_{i+1}').save()

query = Person.select().where(Person.name == "123' or '1' = '1")
print(query)
print(len(list(query)))
```

Результат:

```sql
SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name" FROM "person" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."name" = '123' or '1' = '1')
0
```

**Как видно, запрос валидный, но ничего не вернуло.**

#### Попробуем выполнить этот же запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Запрос валидный.**

Так что же на самом деле [peewee](/questions/tagged/peewee) передает драйверу базы данных?

Как посмотреть этот запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы увидеть выполняемые запросы, нужно установить [логирование](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#logging-queries), добавив код:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('peewee')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

И как видим, данные передаются через биндинг, поэтому будет экранировано и не будет опасности sql-инъекции:

```sql
SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name" FROM "person" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."name" = '123' or '1' = '1')
0
('SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."name" FROM "person" AS "t1" WHERE ("t1"."name" = ?)', ["123' or '1' = '1"])
```